# $y''+y=x^2+1, y(\pi)=\pi^2, y'(\pi)=2\pi$ - By Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I am solving the following IVP by Laplace Transform:

$$y''+y=x^2+1,\qquad y(\pi)=\pi^2, \qquad y'(\pi)=2\pi$$

Let $f(x)=u_{\pi}(x)y(x-\pi).$ Then,
$$f''(x)+f'(x)=u_{\pi}(x)(x-\pi)^2+u_{\pi}(x), \qquad f(0)=\pi ^2, \qquad f'(0)=2\pi.$$

Using the Laplace Transform and writing $F:=\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)$, we have
$$s^2F-sf(0)-f'(0)+F=e^{-\pi s}\dfrac{s+1}{s^2},$$
$$(s^2+1)F-(s+1)\pi^2-2\pi=e^{-\pi s}\dfrac{s+1}{s^2},$$
$$F=e^{-\pi s}\dfrac{s+1}{s^2(s^2+1)}+\dfrac{(s+1)\pi^2}{(s^2 +1)}+\dfrac{2\pi}{(s^2+1)}.$$

Be
$$\dfrac{s+1}{s^2(s^2+1)}=\dfrac{As+B}{s^2}+\dfrac{Cs+D}{s^2+1}. $$

We have
$$As^3+As+Bs^2+B+Cs^3+Ds^2=s+1,$$
$$A+C=0, B+D=0, A=1, B=1,$$
$$C=-1, D=-1, A=1, B=1.$$

So,
$$\dfrac{s+1}{s^2(s^2+1)}=\dfrac{s+1}{s^2}-\dfrac{s+1}{s^2+1}= \dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{1}{s^2}-\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}-\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}.$$

Then,
$$F=e^{-\pi s}\left(\dfrac{1}{s}+\dfrac{1}{s^2}-\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}-\dfrac {1}{s^2+1}\right)+\pi^2\left(\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}\right)+ 2\pi\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}.$$

By the inverse transform,
$$f(x)=u_\pi(x)\left(1+(x-\pi)-\cos(x-\pi)-\sin(x-\pi)\right)+\pi^2 \left(\cos(x)+\sin(x)\right)+2\pi\sin(x).$$

Returning to the variable $y$ and remembering that $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$, we have

$$y(x)=1+x-\cos(x)-\sin(x)+\pi^2(-\cos(x)-\sin(x))-2\pi \sin (x) .$$

> However, the Wolfram's solution is $y(x)=-1 + x^2 - \cos(x)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you use the Laplace transform to the ODE, it seems you mistook $y$ for $y'$ in the LHS of the ODE $y''+y=x^2+1$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Oh nice... You're right. I'll try to fix!

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I fixed, the answer is better, but I am yet cannot get the correct function :/

Comment: Doesn't look fixed. The LHS would be $(s^2+1)F-\color{red}{s}\pi^2-2\pi$ after applying the transform. But more importantly, you need to first make sure your initial conditions at $\pi$ become initial conditions at $0$ after the sub. With the substitution $f(x)=u_\pi(x)y(x-\pi)$ that you did, note that $f(0),f'(0)$ are actually $y(-\pi),y'(-\pi)$ instead of at $+\pi$

Comment: Oh what a mess I am doing. Sorry, and thank you really much!

Comment: No worries, what I would suggest is to first rewrite the ODE with a variable change $\eta=x-\pi$ that would give you $y''(\eta+\pi)+y(\eta+\pi)=(\eta+\pi)^2+1$ and then write $u(\eta)=y(\eta+\pi)$ to get $u''(\eta)+u(\eta)=(\eta+\pi)^2+1$ with the initial conditions now at $u(0)=\pi^2,~u'(0)=2\pi$ and then go through solving it with Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you, I 'll do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Laplace transformation we have

$$
Y(s) = \frac{s^2+y_0s^4+s^3y'_0+2}{s^3(s^2+1)}
$$

with inverse

$$
y(x) = x^2+\sin (x) y'_0+y_0 \cos (x)+\cos (x)-1
$$

here $y_0$ and $y'_0$ are generic constants so imposing the initial conditions we have

$$
\cases{
y(\pi) = \pi^2-y_0-2=\pi^2\\
y'(\pi) = 2\pi-y'_0=2\pi
}
$$

and solving we have $y_0 = -2,\ y'_0 = 0$
hence

$$
y(x) = x^2-\cos x-1
$$

Comment: Thank you so much